# finding an element in an array without using include?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I have an array of objects in which I need to check if it meets a specific criteria.

What I've done is looped through the array and then matched it with the ruby `include?` object.  Problem is I've noticed that there are instances where this causes some codes to return true, when they really should be returning false.

```
group.plan_codes.each do |code|
   normalized_plan_code = code.upcase.gsub(" ", "").gsub("+", "")
   normalized_plan_code.include? coverage['plan_description'].upcase.gsub(" ", "").gsub("+", "")
end
```

I'm basically taking these `group.plan_codes` and matching them with the `coverage['plan_description']`.  Problem I found was that if the code was something like `group plan` submitting a code like `not group plan` would still return true because the `group plan` is included in the `plan description`

Would anyone know a better way about doing this? I was thinking it could stop looking after the first element is completed, but am a little caught up on the ruby `detect`

Comment: Does every object of your array should meet your specific criteria? If so, use `all?` instead.

Comment: no, only one really. I just need to find the first one.

Comment: Therefore, you should use `#find` (`#detect` is an alias). It will find and return the first one.

Comment: And replace `gsub(" ", "").gsub("+", "")` with `delete('+ ')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`Regex`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Regexp.html) or a straight equality test (`==`). For sake of clarity, let's assume (that I'm understanding your question correctly and) that you have an array such as:

```
plans = [ 'not group plan', 'group plan' ]
```

and you are trying to find the second element:

```
including = 'group plan'
plans.detect { |plan| plan.include?(including) }
```

this returns "not group plan", the first element, because it also includes the string 'group plan'. To remedy that, using regex you could use something like:

```
plans.detect { |plan| plan.match?(/\A#{Regexp.escape(including)}\z/) }
```

Now, this returns the second element, because you're looking for an exact match. Since it is an exact match, though, you could also use something simpler:

```
plans.detect { |plan| plan == including }
```

What the regex gives you is if each plan can include multiple items:

```
plans = ['plan a,not group plan,plan b', 'plan a,group plan,plan b']
```

Which is a comma separated list of plan codes and you're looking for any plan that includes 'group plan', now you can use the regex:

```
plans.detect { |plan| plan.match?(/,#{Regexp.escape(including)},/) }
```

and have the second element returned. You'll need to work the regex into a format that works for how you are saving the plan codes (in this example, I chose comma separated list, you might have tabs or semicolons or whatever else. If you have just a white space separated list of codes that can contain whitespace, you need to do more work and `reject` any items that include any codes that are longer and include the code you're looking for.